# WS02: Identity Server: "No SaaS SAML service providers found for the issuer"

Tags: java, wso2, idp, wso2-identity-server

I've been able to set up a federated SSO SAML2 using OpenAM but when attempting to use WS02's Identity Server as the resident IDP I'm getting the following error.

```
response back to: /samlsso...
commonAuthAuthenticated: true
authenticatedUser: wmAdmin
authenticatedIdPs: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCAiYWxnIjoibm9uZSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJ3c28yIiwiZXhwIjoxNTI4MjI5ODYwOTEyMzAwMCwiaWF0IjoxNTI4MjI5ODYwOTEyLCJpZHBzIjpbeyJpZHAiOiJMT0NBTCIsImF1dGhlbnRpY2F0b3IiOiJCYXNpY0F1dGhlbnRpY2F0b3IifV19.
sessionDataKey: d4e6915d-96fb-4ed0-a8b7-2163f6f6ad00 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-06-05 16:17:40,984] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet} -  Query string : null 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-06-05 16:17:40,984] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet} -  No SaaS SAML service providers found for the issuer : wmSP. Checking for SAML service providers registered in tenant domain : carbon.super 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-06-05 16:17:40,985] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet} -  Error when processing the authentication request! 
org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityException: Error while reading service provider configurations for issuer : wmSP in tenant domain : carbon.super
```

What should I look for to solve this error?  Through the browser I'm able to go from the service provider URL and get directed to the WSO2 resident IDP login screen.  After typing in the password and submitting I end up in the error page.  Any ideas what might be miss-configured?

**Full call stack:**

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-06-05 16:17:40,984] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultAuthenticationRequestHandler} -  Sending response back to: /samlsso...
commonAuthAuthenticated: true
authenticatedUser: wmAdmin
authenticatedIdPs: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCAiYWxnIjoibm9uZSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJ3c28yIiwiZXhwIjoxNTI4MjI5ODYwOTEyMzAwMCwiaWF0IjoxNTI4MjI5ODYwOTEyLCJpZHBzIjpbeyJpZHAiOiJMT0NBTCIsImF1dGhlbnRpY2F0b3IiOiJCYXNpY0F1dGhlbnRpY2F0b3IifV19.
sessionDataKey: d4e6915d-96fb-4ed0-a8b7-2163f6f6ad00 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-06-05 16:17:40,984] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet} -  Query string : null 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-06-05 16:17:40,984] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet} -  No SaaS SAML service providers found for the issuer : wmSP. Checking for SAML service providers registered in tenant domain : carbon.super 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-06-05 16:17:40,985] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet} -  Error when processing the authentication request! 
org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityException: Error while reading service provider configurations for issuer : wmSP in tenant domain : carbon.super
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityException.error(IdentityException.java:91)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.getServiceProviderConfig(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:1333)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleAuthenticationReponseFromFramework(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:762)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleRequest(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:209)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.doGet(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:107)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.sendRequestToFramework(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:1205)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleRequest(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:171)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.doPost(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:119)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.captcha.filter.CaptchaFilter.doFilter(CaptchaFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:65)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:60)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.exception.IdentitySAML2SSOException: Error occurred while retrieving SAML service provider for issuer : wmSP in tenant domain : carbon.super
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.getServiceProviderConfig(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:1322)
        ... 59 more
```

Comment: Can you please explain your use case a bit more? What are the roles of OpenAM and WSO2 Identity Server in your use case.

Comment: The only connection between OpenAM and WS02 is to replicate the same federated SAML2 SSO and have access to the service provider.  Using OpenAM I was able to log in and have access to the service provider.  When I replaced OPenAM to WS02 IS, using its resident IDP and registering the service provider I'm getting the above error.

Comment: Here's what I did in WS02:
Created the role 'Manager'
Created the user wmAdmin that has the role Manager
Created Service Provider wmSP by importing the service provider metadata.  The same one used in the OpenAM use case.
Extracted the IDP metadata from WS02 IS and replaced the idp.xml in the fedlet service provider's folder

I was expecting the service provider to redirect to the WS02 IS log in page.  This happens.
After typing the username and password I'm not redirect back to the service provider's page.  That's kind of where I'm stuck.

Comment: Will you be able to point us to a SAML trace so that we can trace the request and responses and understand what's going on

Comment: Fedlet debug folder logs: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1abcyYwpCrRg9l9TMYxcXl-UxtlxkSUlS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: WS02 IS 5.5.0 logs: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OO9Sy9V44zX9c_bJ21QmGxWZtrBsLEIS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: By the way I downloaded 5.4.1 and I'm able to authenticate, get redirected to the application and use it.  It works in 5.4.1.

Comment: Can you login to management console and check following registry path? /_system/config/repository/identity/SAMLSSO . see if there is any resource with name d21TUA== in this path

Comment: Maduranga, the resource path exits (/_system/config/repository/identity/SAMLSSO/d21TUA).